# using columns breaks the compilation of the document

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, two-column

while using the beamer class to try to make this slide
[image]

2 things poped up-

1. When try to use columns it breaks the document
2. The coordinates gets messed since the circle expected (thanks to
   abcdefg) does not appear,nor the center or the arrow.

the code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Circle thing}

\begin{block}{ $x^{2}+y^{2}-2x+6y+7=0$}
\end{block}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item$x^{2}+y^{2}-2x+6y+7=0$
\item$x^{2}-2x+y^{2}-6y+7=0$
\item$x^{2}-2x+1-1+y^{2}-6y+9-9+7=0$
\item$(x-1)^{2}-1+(y-3)^{2}-9+7=0$
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=0cm]
     \begin{axis}[
        scale=0.8,
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=-1, xmax=3, ymin=-1, ymax=7,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        yticklabels={0,...,5},
        grid=both,
        ]
        \draw (50,3) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$C$](c0) {} circle [radius={sqrt(3)}];
        \draw[-stealth] (c0) to[edge label={$\sqrt{3}$}] ++
        (axis direction cs:{sqrt(3)*cos(-45)},{sqrt(3)*sin(-45)}) ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}
\end{column}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have checked for open statements and if the preamble have something strange; also I don't get why the columns tags are wrecking the file.
I understand the coordinates starts from the middle of the documents (as a cartesian plane) and in other configurations the coordinates are anchored to the bottom left (but I don't remember if this is a invention o mine or really read it).

**UPDATE**
using the answer of **abcdefg**  , it gets the next output
[image]
it seems to be marking a node, but well outside the (1,3), I was using (50,3) as test to see if it was appearing somewhere, but in both cases the same draw shows up.

**2nd UPDATE**
The fail was in the

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
```

I changed to

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
```

and this made the trick.

Comment: You've forgotten `\end{columns}` at least.

Comment: Thanks, even when I try harder these things slip between the code.

Comment: @riccs_0x: Sorry for OT. However, there is an inconsistency in your calculations (consider the first two items above: `+6y` and `-6y`). Best regards.

Comment: @MarianG., thanks for taking your time Im reviewing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [pointed out by Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571964/using-columns-breaks-the-compilation-of-the-document#comment1441233_571964), you forgot `\end{columns}`. In addition, I am using [this post](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1480#a1711) to fix the widths of the columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads \usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Circle thing}

\begin{block}{$x^{2}+y^{2}-2x+6y+7=0$}
\end{block}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]% see https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1480#a1711
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item$x^{2}+y^{2}-2x+6y+7=0$
\item$x^{2}-2x+y^{2}-6y+7=0$
\item$x^{2}-2x+1-1+y^{2}-6y+9-9+7=0$
\item$(x-1)^{2}-1+(y-3)^{2}-9+7=0$
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{\dimexpr\textwidth-5cm}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=0cm]
     \begin{axis}[
        scale=0.8,
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=-1, xmax=3, ymin=-1, ymax=7,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        yticklabels={0,...,5},
        grid=both,
        ]
        \draw (50,3) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$C$](c0) {}
         circle [radius={sqrt(3)}];
        \draw[-stealth] (c0) to[edge label={$\sqrt{3}$}] ++
        (axis direction cs:{sqrt(3)*cos(-45)},{sqrt(3)*sin(-45)}) ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, the circle gets clipped away because it gets drawn at `(50,3)` which is well outside the domain set by `xmin=-1, xmax=3, ymin=-1, ymax=7,`. If you use `\draw (1,3) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$C$](c0) {}
   circle [radius={sqrt(3)}];` you get a neat fluffy circle.

Comment: I was supposing the same, but Im getting something odd, like one node is marked only and out of the limits and where isnt supposed to be, Im posting in the question, thanks for the columns these work better.